# Get max subject to conditions from another dataset's variable

Tags: r

Here's a reproducible example:

```
year <- as.vector(c(rep(1949,5), rep(1950,5), rep(1951,5), rep(1952,5)))
bracket <- as.vector(c(rep(c(10,20,30,40,50),4)))

datasmall <- as.data.frame(cbind(year,bracket))

yearbig <- as.vector(c(rep(1949,10), rep(1950,10), rep(1951,10), rep(1952,11)))
earnings <- as.vector(runif(41, 10, 60))

databig <- as.data.frame(cbind(yearbig,earnings))
```

I want to create a new variable in the big database (let's call it maxbracket) that has the maximum bracket value from "datasmall" in a common given year (brackets values can change each year) among those only bracket values below the value of each given earnings observation.

I tried this:

```
databig$maxbracket <- NA
for (i in 1949:1952) {
databig$maxbracket[databig$yearbig==i] <- max(datasmall$bracket[datasmall$year==i & 
(datasmall$bracket < databig$earnings[databig$yearbig==i])], na.rm = T)}
```

But it gives me an error. Any help welcome! Thanks!!

Comment: What is `rate` ?

Comment: It's not reproducible at the moment as you haven't defined `rate` so `datasmall` can't be created. In general though, loops should be avoided where possible - you could create a temporary object which merges the two data frames and work from there, then you run vectorised operations which are usually much faster.

Comment: Sorry, rate variable shouldn't have been there. Edited now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then with base R you may do

```
databig$maxbracket <- mapply(function(y, e) 
  with(datasmall, max(bracket[year == y & bracket < e])), databig$yearbig, databig$earnings)
head(databig, 3)
#   yearbig earnings maxbracket
# 1    1949 12.32897         10
# 2    1949 10.87209         10
# 3    1949 50.04304         50
```

which is similar to your approach, just using `mapply`. In particular, there is no good reason to do any grouping by year here. So, we have a two-variate anonymous function taking a year and earnings, to which we provide the two columns of `databig` and apply them row by row. Given a specific pair `(y,e)` of `databig`, we look for a maximum `bracket` in `datasmall` such that `year == y & bracket < e`.

Comment: @JuanC, great, added some more explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `rate` is not needed in `datasmall`:

```
library(tidyverse)

databig %>%
  left_join(datasmall, by = c("yearbig" = "year")) %>%
  group_by(yearbig) %>%
  filter(bracket < earnings) %>%
  filter(max(bracket) == bracket)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#> # Groups:   yearbig [4]
#>   yearbig earnings bracket
#>     <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1    1949     47.7      40
#> 2    1949     43.8      40
#> 3    1949     46.6      40
#> 4    1950     55.4      50
#> 5    1950     59.1      50
#> 6    1950     55.1      50
#> 7    1951     50.0      50
#> 8    1952     51.6      50
#> 9    1952     52.8      50
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll check the other answer in base R but this works too.

Comment: @JuanC You'll want to play with both, it looks like we interpreted the question differently so we arrive at different results.

Comment: Thanks! I think for my purposes you would need to group by yearbig _and_ earnings in the second line: `group_by(yearbig, earnings) %>%`  since it seems the `left_join` command creates additional earnings value for each bracket-year. This way I think one gets the same result (and the right number of observations). Otherwise it seems only observations above the max bracket for each year remain.